# Not able to access action bar of app when bottom sheet is opened

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a bookmark button in the action bar which is not clickable when I open a bottom sheet by clicking a button (the button is in fragment).

Here is the code :

**activity_learn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".learn.LearnActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**mcq_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_cyan">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_close"
                style="@style/ic_close"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
                style="@style/progressBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardNumber"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ic_close"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                ......more code ......

<com.adithya.memoneet.utils.FButton
                android:id="@+id/check_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quando"
                android:text="Check"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:buttonColor="@color/light_gray"
                app:cornerRadius="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear_layout"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**correct_wrong_bottom_sheet_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    app:behavior_hideable= "true"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/fredoka_one"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="1sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Oops! Correct Answer is: \nHeart" />

            <ozaydin.serkan.com.image_zoom_view.ImageViewZoom
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_memoneet"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview" />

            <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:autoPlay="false"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
                app:showFullScreenButton="true"
                app:showYouTubeButton="false" />

            <com.adithya.memoneet.utils.FButton
                android:id="@+id/continue_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quando"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:buttonColor="@color/light_gray"
                app:cornerRadius="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/youtube_player_view"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**McqFragment.java**

```
//below function is called when the user clicks the button in MCQ fragment

 public static void showCorrectWrongBottomSheetDialog(final FragmentActivity activity, String answer, String explanation, boolean correct, String subjectType, final CallBackListener callBackListener) {
        try {
            final BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(activity);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.01f);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.correct_wrong_bottom_sheet_dialog);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            ConstraintLayout bottom_layout = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);
            FButton continue_button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
            TextView textview = dialog.findViewById(R.id.textview);

            String finalExplanation;
            AppCompatImageView imageView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);

            ..more code..
}
```

when the bottom sheet is opened in mcq fragment I am not able to click the bookmark button in action bar

Comment: The bottom sheet is just a modified dialog, so everything will be inaccessible in the background. Try modal bottom sheet instead of dialog.

Comment: @AnkitVerma ok I will try it and let you know, should I follow this? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modal-bottom-sheet-in-android-with-examples/

Comment: Actually you should use  a persistent bottom sheet , not a modal bottom sheet.
You can follow this video https://youtu.be/x_juFIQeTgI